# CSS half page sticky half scroll not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate [this](https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/2748?siteId=26f031ff-bf63-435a-8cbf-f0a55ca66fb3&metaSiteId=8e4730c7-b994-49ea-af94-6caccfe3e705&originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fportfolio-cv%2Fpersonal&tpClick=view_button) layout but for some reason my code won't work correctly. The image sticks for a second but then continues to scroll like a normal webpage. I have tried to recreate the website but with multiple sticky images as you scroll down. One problem is that instead of the text scrolling, it now overflows:
[image]

This is my code:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

section div.sectionText {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.sectionContainer {
  height: 100vh;
}

section div.stickyContainer {
  height: 92vh;
  background-color: lavender;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 8vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section div.img-2 {
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}

.stickyImg {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2vw;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="sectionText" style="margin-top: 8vh; height: 92vh;">
    <p class="title bold">Title Page</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stickyContainer">
    <img src="MainImgCrop.jpeg" class="stickyImg" />
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="sectionText">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class="stickyContainer img-2"></div>
</section>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The element is being stickied to `<section>`, not the whole body. You need to move the element outside of the `<section>`

Comment: @Rojo sorry, would you be able to explain further? thank you!

Comment: Basically, `sticky` makes the element "stick" to the top of the parent element. If your `<section>` was scrollable, then `<div class="stickyContainer img-2">` would stick to the top of the section that you're scrolling. If the parent element is `<body>` then the element would stick to the top of `<body>`

Comment: you are wrong there @Rojo. `sticky` does not stick to the parent element. `sticky` is a value that followes the normal flow and changes it state to `position: fixed` if a certain position (viewport not body or parent element) is reached. However, as `sticky` follows the flow, it also will be moved out of the viewport if the parent element leaves it as it still has to follow the flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have found my error by commenting lines of the code and seeing what is affected. I originally had `height: 100vh;` in `section div.sectionText` but removing this fixes it completely.